# "Undefined control sequence" error when using chemfig in ConTeXt

Tags: context, chemfig

I came across an error when using `chemfig` in ConTeXt:

```
\usemodule[chemfig]

\starttext

\chemfig{A-B}

\stoptext
```

There is no pdf output, but there is an error message:

```
%%%%

tex error       > tex error on line 4 in file d:/context/chem/li02.tex: ! Undefined control sequence

<argument> \CF@end@tikzpicture 

\CF@exp@macroarg ...expandafter #1\expandafter {#2
                                                  }
\CF@exp@second ...F@exp@macroarg \CF@swap@arg {#2}
                                                  {#1}
<to be read again> 
{
l.4     \chemfig{
               A-B}

1     \usemodule[chemfig]
2     
3     \starttext
4 >>      \chemfig{A-B}
5     \stoptext


? 

%%%%
```

But `chemfig` code like that works in LaTeX. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don't have the module, but you could try the syntax `\chemfig[A-B]`. In context [] are used for mandatory argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. I modified the braces to the bracket, but it turned out the same error as above. It seems that braces/bractets are not relevant to the error. I use TeX Live 2018, which ConTeXt is included.

Comment: The code also works on my older installation of context (2015.05.18), but not on my newer installation (2018.04.04).

Comment: FWIW, ConTeXt also has built-in support for chemical formulas. See the [PPCHTEX manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mp-ch-en.pdf) for details.

Comment: @Aditya `PPCHTEX` is good, but I think the major frustration in using it is the lacking of revised manual. The latest manual we can found was released in 2001, and the topic of chemistry on contextgarden has not been updated for a long time. Alan said he was responsible for the new manual on the mailing list in 2016, but I had not seen it until now. Anyway, I will wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I take a look at the LaTeX implementation `chemfig.sty` I find (with some irrelevant stuff omitted)

```
\input chemfig.tex
\def\printatom#1{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}% \printatom pour LaTeX.
\def\CF@begin@tikzpicture{\begin{tikzpicture}}%
\def\CF@end@tikzpicture{\end{tikzpicture}}%
```

However the ConTeXt module lacks all of those definitions.  Therefore you have to mimic them yourself.  This should be fixed in the chemfig package itself.  If I find the time, I will report it on the [issue tracker](https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/chemfig/issues).

```
\usemodule[chemfig]

\def\printatom#1{\mathematics{\mathrm#1}}
\setvalue{CF@begin@tikzpicture}{\tikzpicture}
\setvalue{CF@end@tikzpicture}{\endtikzpicture}

\starttext

\chemfig{A-B}

\stoptext
```